# File csv does not downloaded but instead open inside browser

Tags: django, csv

I have two files that a user can download from my django app. The files have different formats xls and csv. The first one is downloaded as expected, but the problem is with csv, it is not downloaded, but opens inside the browser like a normal html. how can this be fixed?

I think I need to change the title from text/html to file/csv. But i don't know how i can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a content disposition header to tell the browser that it's an attachment?  Browsers can have different default actions for different file types.

```py
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename.csv"'
```

Comment: I didn't use it. Do you offer to create a new view for specify that header?

Comment: It depends how you're serving the files.  You could have a single view that chooses can supply several file types, basing headers and output based on the file extension, or you could have separate views for each extension.

Comment: Your advice solved my problem, I created new view in my django with your string of code, thanks.